# Grouping elements in array by multiple properties underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

During work, I was given this task : to group elements with similar properties in the array.

In general, the problem is as follows :

```
var order = [
    {
        "tot":1,
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"OFFSITE",
        "equipment":"37 P 552 A",
        "parameter":"Speed"
    }, {
        "tot":1,
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"OFFSITE",
        "equipment":"37 P 552 A",
        "parameter":"Discharge pressure"
    }, {
        "tot":1,
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"OFFSITE",
        "equipment":"37 P 552 A",
        "parameter":"Speed"
    }, {
        "tot":1,
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"RCU",
        "equipment":"37 P 552 B",
        "parameter":"Discharge pressure"
    }
]
```

If I group this elements by 'ru', 'area', 'unit', 'tot', 'equipment' and 'parameter', I will get this result :

```
var result = [
    {
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"OFFSITE",
        "tot":2,
        "equipment":"37 P 552 A",
        "parameter":"Speed"
    }, {
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"OFFSITE",
        "tot":1,
        "equipment":"37 P 552 A",
        "parameter":"Discharge Pressure"
    }, {
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"RCU",
        "tot":1,
        "equipment":"37 P 552 B",
        "parameter":"Discharge Pressure"
    }];
```

After some experimentation, I came to the following code :

```
  var groups = _.groupBy(order, function(value) {
    return value.ru + "#" + value.area + "#" + value.unit + "#" + value.equipment + "#" + value.parameter + "#";
  });

  groups = _.map(groups, function(group) {
    return _.extend(group[0], {tot: group.length});
  });
```

Now I have problem how to group the similar result elements. If there is someone around here, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by similar result elements?

Comment: @Andreas how to group the result data above, because the result have some similar elements.

Comment: Then, what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: This solution works, but is this a right and best way? It still looks a little ugly to me.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly, because currently you are saying that you have a problem with the grouping, not with the optimizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```js
var order = [
    {
        "tot":1,
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"OFFSITE",
        "equipment":"37 P 552 A",
        "parameter":"Speed"
    }, {
        "tot":1,
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"OFFSITE",
        "equipment":"37 P 552 A",
        "parameter":"Discharge pressure"
    }, {
        "tot":1,
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"OFFSITE",
        "equipment":"37 P 552 A",
        "parameter":"Speed"
    }, {
        "tot":1,
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"RCU",
        "equipment":"37 P 552 B",
        "parameter":"Discharge pressure"
    }
];
var result = [];
order.forEach(current=>{
    let index = -1;
    result.forEach((c,i)=>{
        if (c.ru==current.ru && c.area==current.area && c.unit==current.unit && c.tot==current.tot && c.equipment==current.equipment && c.parameter==current.parameter){
            index = i;
        }
    });
    // console.log(index);
    if(index==-1){
        result.push(current);
    }else{
        result[index]["tot"] = result[index]["tot"]+current["tot"];
    }
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: how to get specific object for example 'ru'?

Comment: Get result just has only "ru"?

Comment: yes, get result only "ru", I think just console.log(result.ru), but the result is undefined

Comment: You can use: `console.log(order.map(current=>current["ru"]));` --> get only column 'ru'!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can avoid grouping and directly update the `tot` property of the merged object in your "index" map/object if you encounter similar elements:

Here is a solution that does that with `reduce`:

```js
const order = [
    {
        "tot":1,
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"OFFSITE",
        "equipment":"37 P 552 A",
        "parameter":"Speed"
    }, {
        "tot":1,
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"OFFSITE",
        "equipment":"37 P 552 A",
        "parameter":"Discharge pressure"
    }, {
        "tot":1,
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"OFFSITE",
        "equipment":"37 P 552 A",
        "parameter":"Speed"
    }, {
        "tot":1,
        "ru":"R401",
        "area":"RFCC",
        "unit":"RCU",
        "equipment":"37 P 552 B",
        "parameter":"Discharge pressure"
    }
]

const merged = Object.values(order.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const key = `${curr.ru}#${curr.area}#${curr.unit}#${curr.equipment}#${curr.parameter}`;
  if (key in acc) acc[key].tot += 1;
  else acc[key] = Object.assign({}, curr);
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(merged);
console.log(merged.map(d => d.ru));
```

Comment: how to get all "ru" objects in array?

Comment: @HamzahAznageel it's not that complicated. As @protoproto said, you can use `map` (see updated answer). `merged.map(d => d.ru)`